# Deploying a Sharepoint Time Job without add references do GAC

Tags: sharepoint, jobs, gac

We have a SharePoint timer job that is deployed by WSP file. The job is installed by a SharePoint feature and its dll is placed on GAC.
Every other SharePoint customization is deploying by another WSP file which is placed on SharePoint Site's bin folder, and not on GAC.

The SharePoint timer job is executed by the service Windows SharePoint Services Timer (OWSTIMER.EXE) and hasn't any http or SharePoint context.

If the job have any external reference we have to put every referenced dll on the GAC too. However, we can't do it because the **server polices don't allow GAC deployment** of anything else beside the job dll...

Then, our team **manually copy and paste the code** that would be referenced and put it inside of the job project and build a giant unique dll. Such duplication process have caused all sort of troubles because of sometimes the code became desynchronized on inside the job. Nevertheless , duplication never is a beautiful thing to do and we know we are going straight to hell when we die because of it.

Is it possible to deploy the job without deploying its references on the gac?
Or is it possible to merge the referenced dlls inside a unique dll?
Or if everything else fails, it is possible to build the project so the referenced code is copied on the compilation time?

Thank you on advanced.

Answer (score 3):

The real problem is your server admins blanket ban on GAC deployment for anything other than the job DLL. Nothing like a policy without considering the implications ;)

The band aid to this is [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx).

> ILMerge is a utility that can be used
>   to merge multiple .NET assemblies into
>   a single assembly. ILMerge takes a set
>   of input assemblies and merges them
>   into one target assembly.

This will allow you to merge your job assembly and all the dependant assemblies into one super job assembly for deployment - much better than manually copy and pasting code. Plus you can do it in the postbuild steps so its all built into your build process.

Comment: I never cease to be amazed at how often well-meaning policies can result in god-awful code

Comment: Hehe - and how many times the letter of said policy is upheld even when the spirit of it is totally trampled upon.

Comment: Thank you, we will try ILMerge, but for sure it looks to be a good solution. The client's deploy policy is a mess, we can't do a lot of stuffs because of it. As if Sharepoint alone wasn't a requirement hell...

Answer (score -1):

Why can't referenced dll be put in the bin directory ? It can certainly be.

Comment: The job is launched by Windows SharePoint Services Timer, not by the the SharePoint site. Because of that the job needs to be deployed on GAC.